# Is there a version control system abstraction for the command-line?

Tags: svn, git, version-control, mercurial

Now that so many small open source projects "ship" via their version control systems, I have dozens of repositories that I need on a frequent basis, often on multiple machines. I'm looking for some kind of way to manage this easily. If I were to design it myself, I would have a file listing all the remote repositories, and a command-line client that automatically pulled from them.

Does this, or some variation on the theme, exist?

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing what you want this for.  If you checkout/clone a repository, you can update without resupplying the repo URL.

Comment: I have dozens of repositories like this, and need to check them out on a number of machines.

Comment: @Karmastan: I also suffer from this problem, I'll need one project that's hosted on an Svn server, one on git, my own code is on Hg. I need to know which project I'm in to get a latest version, or commit. The OP wants to know has someone developed a "One Size Fits All" wrapper that *knows* what the repository is and applies the requisit command? e.g. `OSFA_Update` *knows* the project is svn and runs `svn up`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[mr](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/mr/) is designed to let you update multiple repositories as one, and supports a wide range of version control systems:

> The mr(1) command can checkout,
>   update, or perform other actions on a
>   set of repositories as if they were
>   one combined respository. It supports
>   any combination of subversion, git,
>   cvs, mercurial, bzr, darcs, cvs, and
>   fossil repositories, and support for
>   other revision control systems can easily be added. (There are extensions adding support for unison and git-svn.)

Comment: Excellent! Another "universal" tool (I wasn't aware of it). +1

Answer (score 3):

The only project I know which aims at providing a common interface (called '**[command](http://amp.carboni.ca/about/commands.html)**') for all the major VCS is [**Amp**](http://amp.carboni.ca/).
But it is still a work in progress and might not be complete enough for your goal.